# Reverse proxy server hotlinking problems

Tags: nginx, apache2, hotlinking

I got the next problem:

Have front-end proxy server, that points to my back-end server. Someone is steeling bandwith true my images so I want to block this from happening. I use a proxy.conf file that goes like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
  server_name site2.com www.site2.com;
  server_name site3.com www.site3.com;
  server_name site4.com www.site4.com;
  server_name site5.com www.site5.com; 


  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://IP-back-end-server.com;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

I tried to put his config on my proxy front-end server:

```
    #hotlinking protection
location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
valid_referers none blocked site1.com www.site1.com;
valid_referers none blocked site2.com www.site2.com;
valid_referers none blocked site3.com www.site3.com;
valid_referers none blocked site4.com www.site4.com;
if ($invalid_referer){
return 403;
}
}
```

but, as a result all the images was blocked, included my pointed domains: site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
site4.com

Second option, I tried to block true htaccess on my backend server:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!^$"
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www.site1.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "\.(gif|jpg|png)$"    "-"   [F,NC]
```

as a result, nothing happened, all the images was displayed for hotlinking. Please help me in this situation. Thanks